# FcgidProcessLifeTime no effect

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fcgi

I'm running PHP handler fcgid

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 3000
FcgidMaxProcesses 3000
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 16
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 1
FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
FcgidIOTimeout 180
IPCConnectTimeout 60
FcgidIdleTimeout 600
FcgidIdleScanInterval 30
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidBusyScanInterval 30
FcgidErrorScanInterval 3
FcgidZombieScanInterval 3
FcgidFixPathinfo 0
FcgidMaxRequestInMem 419430400
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

The processes is terminated every 10 mintues or more, Also i set `FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200`

I'm using `mpm_worker` as well :

```
Timeout 50    
<IfModule worker.c>
      StartServers          16
      ServerLimit           1800
      MaxClients            1728
      MinSpareThreads       75
      MaxSpareThreads       250
      ThreadLimit          600
      ThreadsPerChild       64
      MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
      KeepAlive             On
      MaxKeepAliveRequests  50
      KeepAliveTimeout      5
    </IfModule>
```

Processor : Dual Intel xeon E5630 
,RAM : 32GB DDR3, PHPv5.3.14

How can i solve this problem .? and keep the process life time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but recently had to address this.

You have `FcgidIdleTimeout 600`.

This means if a process is idle for 10 minutes it will be terminated regardless of what you set in `FcgidProcessLifeTime`.

I've not tested this but if you wanted to confirm you could set `FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1` and then send requests every 5 minutes.  This should keep this process around for `FcgidProcessLifeTime` because it would never be idle for `FcgidIdleTimeout`.

So an optimized configuration will depend on your work load.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to php-fpm with mod_fastcgi or mod_proxy_fcgi (requires Aapache 2.4). PHP-FPM does it's own process managing and you can even choose different
process managers suitable for your site.

php-fpm becomes more and more the standard way to deploy php apps.